# Per- request based Object Context and Complied Query Performance with Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1

I'm currently working with WCF services application and we've created per request based Object Context of Entity framework. In the entity framework queries, we've used Complied Query mechanism, however, expected performance could not be achieved at the moment. I suspect it is due to the nature of Object Context(Per request based),as Complied queried depends on Object Context. Is it so?

Code Sample

```
private static readonly Func<MyContext, IQueryable<Order>> _compiledObjectQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile<MyContext, IQueryable<Order>>(
        (ctx) => from Order in ctx.Orders
                   .Include("OrderType")
           .Include("OrderLines")                       
               select Order
        );

    protected override IQueryable<Order> OrderQuery
    {
        get { return _compiledObjectQuery.Invoke(Context); }
    }
```

Context Creating

```
public OPDbContext DbContext
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(_dbConext == null)
            {
                _dbConext = new OPDbContext(Context, true);
            }

            return _dbConext;
        }
    }
```

Castle is used to inject Object Context per request base

Comment: Show some example how you do that.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Sorry for the delay. I have include the code sample  thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What was expected performance? Your compiled query definition looks correct. Your property is little bit suspicious because it gets context instance from somewhere and you didn't show how is your context created. Btw. what binding are you using in your service?

Comment: we are using netTcp binding and client is Silverlight. .At the moment we are using this for getting the support of includes with out lazy loading. What my worry is when we create a new context per request and the impact it gives to compiled query.

Comment: How/where do you create context? NetTcp binding uses per session service instancing. Per request context doesn't have any impact on compiled query.